# t.test array funct

Tags: arrays, excel, function

I'm trying to analyse some data. I have it on excel and I'm fairly new at this but I did not see any topic that could've helped me with my problem.

What I have is 2 sets of data on different sheets. I'm trying to determine the P-value between these data. But the way I have the data is displayed in the colums as such,

- If condition A is true, `0`.
- If condition B is true, `1`.

So the bare data is in an array form of `{1,2,0,0,0,0,6,7,4,3,2}`.

I want to calculate the P-value of only condition A. So I employed `IF(A1:A800=0,1,0)` for array1 and 2. It looks like this

```
=T.TEST(IF('Raw Data'!H6:H794=0,1,0),IF(J7:J39=0,1,0),2,2)
```

I keep getting `#VALUE!` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array formulas need to be entered with a specific key combination

Select cell with formula - press **<kbd>F2</kbd>** key to select formula and then hold down **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** and **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** keys while pressing **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**. If done correctly this will put curly braces like { and } around the formula in the formula bar.....and formula should work

The above needs to be repeated if the formula is amended